# tango with django "Like Button" Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I followed this Tutorial 
http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/ajax.html#add-a-like-button
but my like count is not incrementing after clicking it.

Here's my code

views.py

```
def like_post(request):

    post_id = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        post_id = request.GET['post.pk']

    likes = 0
    if post_id:
        post = Post.objects.get(id=int(post_id))
        if post:
            likes = post.likes + 1
            post.likes =  likes
            post.save()

    return HttpResponse(likes)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'like_post/$', views.like_post, name='like_post'),
```

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

post_deatil.html

```
<strong id="like_count">{{ post.likes }}</strong> people like this category

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <button id="likes" data-post_id="{{post.id}}"  class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
        Like
        </button>
{% endif %}
```

blog-ajax.js

```
$('#likes').click(function(){
    var postid;
    catid = $(this).attr("data-post_id");
    $.get('/blog/like_post/', {post_id: postid}, function(data){
               $('#like_count').html(data);
               $('#likes').hide();
    });
});
```

Console message

```
Internal Server Error: /blog/like_post/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bharat/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 83, in __getitem__
    list_ = super(MultiValueDict, self).__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'post.pk'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bharat/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/bharat/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/home/bharat/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/bharat/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/bharat/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bharat/Desktop/DiggingIntoDjango-TreasuregramSampleApp-master/my-first-blog-master/blog/views.py", line 103, in like_post
    post_id = request.GET['post.pk']
  File "/home/bharat/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 85, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'post.pk'"
Internal Server Error: /blog/like_post/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bharat/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 83, in __getitem__
    list_ = super(MultiValueDict, self).__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'post.pk'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bharat/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/bharat/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/home/bharat/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/bharat/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/bharat/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bharat/Desktop/DiggingIntoDjango-TreasuregramSampleApp-master/my-first-blog-master/blog/views.py", line 103, in like_post
    post_id = request.GET['post.pk']
  File "/home/bharat/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 85, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'post.pk'"
[19/Apr/2017 13:03:36] "GET /blog/like_post/ HTTP/1.1" 500 16637
[19/Apr/2017 13:03:36] "GET /blog/like_post/ HTTP/1.1" 500 16637
```

[This is how i get, but after clicking on like nothing happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QudOp.png)

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In views.py use:

```
post_id = None
if request.method == 'GET':
    post_id = request.GET['post_id']
```

instead of:

```
post_id = None
if request.method == 'GET':
    post_id = request.GET['post.pk']
```

This is because in your blog-ajax.js you make a GET-call with parameter 'post_id' and not 'post.pk'

Comment: no luck with that got this in terminal     Internal Server Error: /blog/like_post/
     Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/bharat/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 83, in __getitem__
    list_ = super(MultiValueDict, self).__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'post_id'
'

Comment: post_id never gets a value in blog-ajax.js. You need to change `var postid; catid = $(this).attr("data-post_id");` to `var postid; postid= $(this).attr("data-post_id");` so that it actually fills the right variable

Comment: Thank you, it works, But how to add dislike button? I mean undo it.